# Recovering chunks of text with a little help from regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am currently attempting to retrieve certain chunks of information from a bigger text, using regexes in PHP. I asked a question a couple of weeks ago, regarding doing the same thing using Javascript. The solution for the Javascript was a somewhat messy one, and I would very much need help doing it using PHP.

Below is a piece of text similar to that I would like to retrieve chunks of text from:

```
===Substantiv===
Någonting kul som det innebär, 
uppenbarligen är det så
alltså en definition på någonting

==Slumpmässig==
Detta är en slumpmässig text mitt i som stör.

?¤% Jag stör ännu mer!

===Adjektiv===
En bra definition som är grym.
Men kanske bättre än så.
Fast ändå inte, 
eller kanske faktiskt.

&56Mer störande skit som poppar in slumpmässigt här.
```

The text I would like to retrieve somehow using regex is...

```
===Adjektiv===
En bra definition som är grym.
Men kanske bättre än så.
Fast ändå inte, 
eller kanske faktiskt.
```

... the rest I would like to remove.

How does one go about putting the text I would like to retrieve nicely into its own string?

Best regards,

**Edit:** That is, I would like to split the chunk that I am after by the blank lines before and after the certain chunk of text, then putting it into a string should it prove to be the correct chunk containing *===Adjektiv===* in this case.

**Edit:** I already know regular expression. The problem I am facing has to do with PHP not supporting lookaheads as far as I have understood.

**Edit:** 
    {{se även|Gift}}

```
==Svenska==
===Adjektiv===
{{sv-adj-t-okomp|mask=}}
'''gift'''
#{{avledning|gifta|perfpart}}; ''(om person)'' som ingått [[äktenskap]]
#:''Vet du om han är '''gift'''?''
#:''Jo, Anders och Emma är '''gifta''' med varandra.''
#:{{besläktade ord|[[gifta#Verb|gifta]], [[gifte#Substantiv|gifte]]}}
#:{{sammansättningar|[[bortgift]], [[ingift]], [[ogift]], [[omgift]]}}
#:{{fraser|[[gift par]]}}

====Översättningar====
{{ö-topp|som ingick äktenskap}}
*bokmål: {{ö+|no|gift}}
*bosniska: {{ö|bs|oženjen}} (för män), {{ö|bs|udata}} (för kvinnor)
*danska: {{ö+|da|gift}}
*engelska: {{ö+|en|married}}
*franska: {{ö+|fr|marié}}
*färöiska: {{ö|fo|giftur}}
{{ö-mitt}}
*isländska: {{ö+|is|giftur}}
*italienska: {{ö+|it|sposato}}
*litauiska: {{ö|lt|susituokęs}}
*tyska: {{ö+|de|verheiratet}}
{{ö-botten}}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130542/discussion-on-question-by-d-ataro-recovering-chunks-of-text-with-a-little-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^|\n\n)\K===Adjektiv===\n(.+(\n|$))+
```

This regex will match without any look aheads or behinds. If you get rid of the \K it should work in java-script but you would get the blank line before the match. Also php supports lookaheads. You could, as in wiktor's comment, use \R instead of \n.

**How it Works**

This regex works by matching the 2 blank lines or the beginning of string using `(^|\n\n)` it then uses \K to say this is actually where you want the start of the match. It then matches `===Adjektiv===\n` which is =`==Adjektiv===` plus a line break. It then proceeds to match as many as many lines which have at least one character on then and the line break or end of sting for that line. It dose this using `(.+(\n|$))+` . matches any no line break with the + operator to match at least 1. it then matches either a line break or end of string. It dose this until it can find no more lines with characters. If you wanted to allow single lines to be empty but stop matching on two you would replace this with `(.+(\n{1,2}|$))+`. Also by warping this last section in () you could the text excluding the heading using the second capturing group.

This also has the advantage in efficiency due to no use of look-aheads or look-behinds.